# simple go function correct syntax (I think) but does not work as expected

Tags: go

very simply this function works:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    for i := 0; i <= 5; i++ {
        fmt.Println(i * i)
        if i == 3 {
           continue
         }
    }
}
```

but this does not:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    i := 0 
    for i <= 5; i++ {
        fmt.Println(i * i)
        if i == 3 {
            continue
        }
    }
}
```

this also does not:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

var i int = 0

func main() {
    for i <= 5; i++ {
        fmt.Println(i * i)
        if i == 3 {
            continue
        }
    }
}
```

the errors returned are:

```
# command-line-arguments
.\main.go:9:18: syntax error: unexpected {, expected semicolon or newline
.\main.go:10:21: syntax error: unexpected newline, expected { after for clause
```

for both of the non working ones.

why is that?

I was expecting all 3 functions to return the same result.
I ran go format and it returned:

```
main.go:7:14: expected boolean or range expression, found simple statement (missing parentheses around composite literal?)
main.go:7:18: expected ';', found '{'
main.go:9:3: expected operand, found 'if'
main.go:13:1: expected declaration, found '}'
exit status 2
```

Comment: You are missing a `;` in front of the _condition expression_ of the [`ForClause`](https://go.dev/ref/spec#For_statements). What you want is this: `for ; i <= 5; i++ {`. `for ; ; {}` is legal, but `for ; {}` is NOT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [for loop](https://go.dev/tour/flowcontrol/1) syntax

```
 The basic for loop has three components separated by semicolons:

    the init statement: executed before the first iteration
    the condition expression: evaluated before every iteration
    the post statement: executed at the end of every iteration
```

So if you want to omit the initialization part, then you should have to start with `;`

```
for ; i <= 5; i++ {
   fmt.Println(i * i)
   if i == 3 {
    continue
   }
}
```

The for loop is flexible and you can use as follows as well

```
for i <= 5 {
    i++
    fmt.Println(i * i)
    if i == 3 {
        continue
    }
}
```

if you omit the init and post statements, then it will work as a `while` loop

Comment: Thank you I can sleep now. I am taking a basic Go lang course. It does not do a great job at explaining the details.

I dont like online courses and they will never be a replacement for a space, such as a classroom where you can ask questions.  Thanks again everyone.

Answer (score 0):

`for loop` in Go has formula as

> for statement; condition expression; statement { ... }

Both snippets did not match the formula, so the compiler will throw an error. You might want to try:

```golang
func main() {
    i := 0
    for ; i <= 5; i++ {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: `statement2` should be `condition`, no?

Comment: You're right, edited, just 1 and 3 are statements, 2 is condition expression. Thanks for pointed out.